# Is it possible to have a single div with 1 background image repeating at seperate sections?

Tags: css, background

Let me explain.

I have a single div, called main. In this div you will find h1 tags and p tags.

At the top of the div, there is a gradient. Lower down, the image will fade into plain white with a border (meaning I can't just have no-repeat and then #FFF as background colour).

Therefore, I was wondering if it's possible to have the white section to continue forever without making an extremely large image and without creating a new div.

Note: The h1 and p tags will be transparent.

Comment: You mean, your border is in the image?

Comment: The border isn't possible using CSS (unless you throw in some scripts) with the 'border' attribute, it has gradient on it etcetc, going left-to-right.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is...see this example.
http://techknack.net/css-trick-two-background-images/

You can do it this way also..

```
#id_test{
background-image: url(../pix/logo_quirksmode.gif), url(../pix/logo_quirksmode_inverted.gif);
}
```

Comment: I'm going to test both and see which is best for me (to look at, edit, markup etc). Thanks and I'll see how they work for me :)

Comment: To add, I think you will have to add `background-position: top, bottom; background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat-y;` for a better UI